# How to re-open closed Android project?

Tags: android, recovery

I am using Eclipse to develop Android projects. I tried to reopen a closed project  but got the following message...

> The project description file
>   (.project) for    is missing.  This
>   file contains important information
>   about the project.  The project will
>   not function properly until this file
>   is restored.

I thought I could just create the project from my source folders (by using Windows Explorer) but the projects are completely gone (and I hadn't backed up to an external drive)

Any suggestions how to get these projects back?

Answer (score 3):

closing a project does not delete the .project file.  something else happened to delete that.

To "recover" from this situation I would do the following:

1. Create a new android project.
2. Close eclipse
3. Copy the source from the former project into the new project (outside of eclipse).
4. Start eclipse.
5. Refresh the new android project.

Comment: If the .project file is missing, the source might also be missing! :S

Answer (score 0):

Is your source for your projects completely gone? Did you check your workspace location?

If you still have your source you can create a new project and copy your source into it. (do this via explorer)

You can also try copying a .project file from another project. After the project opens you can then right click on the project and select 'fix project properties'

Answer (score 0):

use window/show view/Package Explore (<kbd>Alt+Shift+ Q P</kbd>)
then in  Package Explore  window select your project
next step project/open project

its take me long time to find it.